# How do i attached file in mongoose( Schema )? when i use String its working but when use File the error occurred --[1]Error: File is not defined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const NoteSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user',
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  description: {
    type: File, //for attachment of file (Error occurred here)
    required: true,
  },

  tag: {
    type: String,
    default: 'General',
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('notes', NoteSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

As We can read in official documentation [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#what-is-a-schematype) about `SchemaTypes` in **Mongoose version 6.6.4** instead of `File` which I cannot find in SchemaTypes (docs) You should use [`Buffer`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#buffers) or `String` as You mention above.
I would also use `source` instead of `description` when it comes abut **files** and Your example above.

Comment: I want to attach files for images or documents, String is not allowed for files.